# How to make a string that consists on one character '-1'?

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm using a class that accepts commands as strings.  Example ...

```
string cmd = "start";
connection->execute(cmd);
```

The 'disconnect' command is any string starting with the character '-1'.  I tried doing this ...

```
string cmd = "0";
cmd[0] = '-1';
connection->execute(cmd);
```

But that produced this error ...

```
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

... how do I create a string that starts with char '-1'?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here - "-1" looks like 2 characters to me?

Comment: A `string` is a sequence of `char`s. The type `char` may be either signed or unsigned. If it's unsigned, then there is no character with the value `-1`, though converting the `int` value `-1` to `char` will *probably* give you a sensible value. It sounds like your requirements are poorly stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the quotes.

```
cmd[0] = -1;
```

Comment: THANKS!  Been pulling my hair out.